# JavaScript object Constructors return properties

Tags: javascript, coding-style

I just want to ask what the advantage of creating JavaScript object model Constructors style like this

```
var PersonTemplate = function () {
    return {
        recordId: 0,
        username: '',
        firstName: '',
        lastName: ''
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By returning an object that is explicitly defined you are breaking the "out-of-the-box" prototypal inheritance chain that's native to JavaScript. Below is a canonical example of using constructors to instantiate new objects that inherit from a prototype...

```
function PersonTemplate(firstName, lastName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName  = lastName;
}
```

From here we can add methods onto `PersonTemplate`'s `protoype`, making use of the protoype chain.

```
PersonTemplate.prototype.sayHello = function() {
    return 'Hello, my name is ' + this.firstName + '!';
} 

var john = new PersonTemplate('John', 'Smith');
john.sayHello(); // => "Hello, my name is John!"
```

Now if we were to try and utilize the prototypal inheritance via your example above (assuming `sayHello` is still added to `PersonTemplate.prototype`, this would be the result...

```
var PersonTemplate = function() {
    return {
        firstName: '',
        lastName: ''
    }
}

var john = new PersonTemplate('John', 'Smith');
john.sayHello(); // => Uncaught TypeError: john.sayHello is not a function
```

By explicitly return an object literal from your constructor, that linkage is broken and you are no longer utilizing "classical" object oriented JavaScript via the prototype chain.

That's not to say there aren't possible esoteric and complicated advantages if one were to expand upon this and put together a novel inheritance technique. Afterall, there are all kinds of creative ways to compose and link objects together (e.g. **OLOO** style by Kyle Simpson [here](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20&%20object%20prototypes/ch6.md), but that's for a larger discussion.